# IPTABLES Redirect a port to another IP

Tags: iptables, ip, redirect

I have tried several post to configure this redirect but is not working, this is what I need

I am receiving packets on port 8080 and I want to redirect the packets to another IP in the same server, why? because for some reason it is not sending this to the internet.

Let me give more detail.

Server A is sending port 2525 to server B but they are not in the same network. I can see the packets coming into Server B but they are not going out to the Internet.

Server B has 2 IP, one is a VPN tun1 connected to Server A and the other IP has Internet access. What I need, or I think I need, is to redirect traffic from the tun1 to the IP that has internet access, I tried different configurations but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding fw rule that would allow that port on the tun1 IP?  As a test (only testing), if you were to tell the app to also listen on that IP on tun1, on that port, does it work?

Comment: HiServer A is running an email server and is sending port 25 to Server B, I wan server B to act like if the email server is there, I can see the traffic coming from server A to server B using the VPN but Server B is doing nothing.

Comment: This is what I have iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.9.6 -i venet0:0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 167.114.185.238 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.9.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0:0 -j MASQUERADE
 and I see this in my firewall on Server B Sep 21 11:41:55 cosiab kernel: [1890626.882859]  INPUT TCP IN=tun1 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.0.10.172 DST=10.0.9.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=65148 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53453 DPT=25 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: And when you do a tcpdump on tun1, do you see packets reaching that interface?  If you do a tcpdump on Server A, do you see packets being forwarded to server B?

Comment: Hi, I see packets coming to Server B Sep 21 11:41:55 cosiab kernel: [1890626.882859]  INPUT TCP IN=tun1 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.0.10.172 DST=10.0.9.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=65148 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53453 DPT=25 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
The IP 10.0.9.6 is on Server B

Comment: and you see server B responding to the correct address?

Comment: Server B gets the packets but is not sending the packets to Internet, for example if I do telnet mail20.ixwebhosting.com 25 Server B gets the packet but is not sending the request to Internet.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Serverfault.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to expose port 25 of 10.0.10.172 on the public address    167.114.185.238, which is owned by server 10.0.9.6

You have the PREROUTING right:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 167.114.185.238 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.0.9.6
```

**But you also need a corresponding POSTROUTING:**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.9.6 -j SNAT --to 10.0.10.172
```

You also mentioned the following FORWARD rule, which is correct:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.9.6 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

But you only need it if you have any DROP rule or policy (-P) on the FORWARD table, which is not    there by default. If you have any DROP rule, then you need to place that ACCEPT **before the DROP   rule**, otherwise it will have no effect.

Finally, you also need to **enable IPv4 forwarding:**

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The following is not really needed, because the connections towards port 25 are originating outside your     server and they already contain your public IP 167.114.185.238 as the destination:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0:0 -j MASQUERADE
```

If this answers your question, make sure to click on the checkmark button ✔ above on the left side.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, the Server A 10.0.10.172 is sending traffic using 10.0.9.6 witch is a VPN connection, this ip is on Server B and Server B has the ip 167.114.185.238, 
I will try your instrucctions and I will let you know if it works, thank you again.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately it didn't work, I see traffic coming to Server B on the ip 10.0.9.6 on my IPTABLES log. Sep 22 07:15:14 cosiab kernel: [1961026.212757]  INPUT TCP IN=tun1 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.0.10.172 DST=10.0.9.6 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=37673 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56081 DPT=25 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: these are my lines for IPTABLES. sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 167.114.185.238 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to 10.0.9.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.9.6 -j SNAT --to 10.0.10.172
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.9.6 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT


iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-prefix ' OUTPUT  TCP ' --log-level 4
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-prefix ' INPUT TCP ' --log-level 4
. I will apreciate any comment.